# Picasso load Url image not working in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Library using build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

Implementation:

```
Picasso.get().load("http://localhost/maestro_ecomm/uploads/products/product_thumb_5d1b2f098900f_29.jpg").placeholder(R.drawable.dustbin).into(holder.prod_user_image)
```

Comment: Whats the error you are getting

Comment: no error showing only show blank

Comment: Plaintext communications are banned by default on modern versions of Android. Use `https` instead of `http`.

Comment: @muruganmani http issue

Comment: If you put that url into a browser address bar, do you get your image? Maybe you need to include a port number?

Answer (score 0):

try below this may help

first create `network_security_config.xml` file at

```
res->xml->
```

which includes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">themaestro.in</domain>

    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

now add   `android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"` this line in Manifest file like below

```
<application
        android:name=".app.MyApplication"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" //notice here
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        .........
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this its working for me in pie and kotlin.

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Update to:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

Load url:

http to https

```
Picasso.get().load("URL PATH").into(Image_view)
```